# Problems re-indexing Category Products in Magento 1.9.1.1

Tags: php, mysql, magento, zend-framework, pdo

I am running Magento 1.9.1.1 on CLOUDLINUX 6.6 x86_64 standard – cpanel  WHM 11.48.4 (build 4).

I get the following error when I run 'php indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_product':

```
Category Products index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`account_mage142`.`mg_catalog_category_product_index`, CONSTRAINT `FK_MG_CAT_CTGR_PRD_IDX_CTGR_ID_MG_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `mg_catalog_category_entity`)' in /home/account/public_html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /home/account/public_html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /home/account/public_html/magento/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/account/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /home/account/public_html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /home/account/public_html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `mg...', Array)
#5 /home/account/public_html/magento/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `mg...', Array)
#6 /home/account/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(179): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `mg...')
#7 /home/account/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Helper/Mysql4.php(49): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Abstract->insertFromSelect(Object(Varien_Db_Select), 'mg_catalog_cate...', Array, false)
#8 /home/account/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(153): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Helper_Mysql4->insertData(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Indexer_Product), Object(Varien_Db_Select), 'mg_catalog_cate...', Array, false)
#9 /home/account/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(113): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Abstract->insertFromTable('mg_catalog_cate...', 'mg_catalog_cate...', false)
#10 /home/account/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Indexer/Product.php(935): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Abstract->syncData()
#11 /home/account/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Indexer_Product->reindexAll()
#12 /home/account/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(212): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#13 /home/account/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(260): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#14 /home/account/public_html/magento/shell/indexer.php(167): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#15 /home/account/public_html/magento/shell/indexer.php(215): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#16 {main}
```

Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]:

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`account_mage142`.`mg_catalog_category_product_index`, CONSTRAINT `FK_MG_CAT_CTGR_PRD_IDX_CTGR_ID_MG_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `mg_catalog_category_entity`), query was: INSERT INTO `mg_catalog_category_product_index` (`category_id`, `product_id`, `position`, `is_parent`, `store_id`, `visibility`) SELECT `mg_catalog_category_product_index_idx`.`category_id`, `mg_catalog_category_product_index_idx`.`product_id`, `mg_catalog_category_product_index_idx`.`position`, `mg_catalog_category_product_index_idx`.`is_parent`, `mg_catalog_category_product_index_idx`.`store_id`, `mg_catalog_category_product_index_idx`.`visibility` FROM `mg_catalog_category_product_index_idx` ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `category_id` = VALUES(`category_id`), `product_id` = VALUES(`product_id`), `position` = VALUES(`position`), `is_parent` = VALUES(`is_parent`), `store_id` = VALUES(`store_id`), `visibility` = VALUES(`visibility`)' in /home/account/public_html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235
Stack trace:
#0 /home/account/public_html/magento/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/account/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/account/public_html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/account/public_html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `mg...', Array)
#4 /home/account/public_html/magento/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `mg...', Array)
#5 /home/account/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(179): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `mg...')
#6 /home/account/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Helper/Mysql4.php(49): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Abstract->insertFromSelect(Object(Varien_Db_Select), 'mg_catalog_cate...', Array, false)
#7 /home/account/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(153): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Helper_Mysql4->insertData(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Indexer_Product), Object(Varien_Db_Select), 'mg_catalog_cate...', Array, false)
#8 /home/account/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(113): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Abstract->insertFromTable('mg_catalog_cate...', 'mg_catalog_cate...', false)
#9 /home/account/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Indexer/Product.php(935): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Abstract->syncData()
#10 /home/account/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Indexer_Product->reindexAll()
#11 /home/account/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(212): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#12 /home/account/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(260): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#13 /home/account/public_html/magento/shell/indexer.php(167): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#14 /home/account/public_html/magento/shell/indexer.php(215): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#15 {main}
```

Any ideas on how I can fix these errors?

Comment: Try truncate all `mg_catalog_category_product*` tables

Comment: This seems to have done the trick; however, does removing the data in this table have any adverse effects to the data in the Magento store?

Comment: That really wasn't a good choice; the relationship between Product and Category would've been lost.

Comment: This operation will truncate only magmi tables, so all relations should be saved.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's possible that you have some category ID in the `catalog_category_product` table that doesn't belong to `catalog_category_entity` anymore. So if the following query returns any result, you can identify the missing category id:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    catalog_category_product AS a
LEFT JOIN catalog_category_entity AS b ON a.category_id = b.entity_id
WHERE
    b.entity_id IS NULL
GROUP BY
    a.category_id
```

After that, you can delete the missing category ID from `catalog_category_product` and `catalog_category_product_index_idx` table using:

```
DELETE
FROM
    catalog_category_product
WHERE
    category_id IN (Comma separated category ID)
```

and

```
DELETE
FROM
    catalog_category_product_index_idx
WHERE
    category_id IN (Comma separated category ID)
```

After that, run the indexing again.